# What does the + mean in the output of "ls -l"?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, acl

```
ls -l

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root   885 2010-07-08 13:55 /etc/backup-number-of-files*
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 levchuk  Users 1067 2010-08-30 14:37 /etc/backup-running-time*
```

Please notice the **+** on the 2nd line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my mind it's always been an indicator that additional permissions are available in the form of ACLs. You should then be able to use [`getfacl`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flinuxcommand.org%2Fman_pages%2Fgetfacl1.html&ei=XK-0TNjAOZDksQPz-bi1CA&usg=AFQjCNFAlZI78j_YSllfBm7Jv2VGZuki2A) to see what those ACLs are.

Comment: You know, I've worked with Unix systems for decades, and I was dimly aware there was an ACL system, but I've never ever seen it used and hadn't a clue how to use it myself.

Comment: I've never seen it documented in an `ls` man page which is why I said "In my mind." Default ACLs can be very useful as a way to work around complex grouping hierarchies, group membership limitations, and permission problems (as generally bestowed by poor SFTP clients).

Comment: Oh... and ACL implementations vary across the board.  `getfacl` works on Linux and (at least some) Solaris, but I've been on other systems that use a completely different implementation.

Comment: I believe there's a POSIX spec (that I've only glanced at briefly) for how they're supposed to work.  I didn't realize that anybody implemented it.  ;-)  I generally disfavor ACLs as I think they lead to excessive complexity and it can become very hard to write code that has a predictable outcome when checking them.  But I agree that they are a very nice tool to have if you absolutely need them.

Comment: I always assumed the + meant I should use lsattr - never heard of getfacl.