# What is the '+' at the end of long listing format?

Tags: macos, unix, administrator, file-permissions, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the + at the end of Unix permissions in a long listing format?](https://superuser.com/questions/399228/what-is-the-at-the-end-of-unix-permissions-in-a-long-listing-format)

Here's an example

```
drwxr-xr-x+  6 reza reza        204 Mar  5 20:23 .ssh/
```

Although I am the owner of this directory, I cannot modify it without using `sudo`.
Why is that? how can I remove '+' here (assuming that is the problem)?

Thanks

Comment: Marked as offtopic, but `man setfacl` anyway.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am runnig OSX, which seems not to have `setfacl` or `getfacl`. Instead the `chmod -N` does fix the problem and removes the ACL; although that works only if you login as **root** and `sudo` does not work...

Comment: Why tagging the question with `linux` then?

Comment: yep, i should have tagged it with `osx`, which i just did

Comment: looks like it's along these lines http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean   http://superuser.com/questions/198758/what-does-the-mean-in-the-acl-output-of-ls-l